# is there any official way in the google docs to start a html5 android app?

Tags: android, html

is there any official way in the google docs to start a html5 android app?

maybe some tutorial in developer.android.com where to start or is this a bad idea to make a html5 app on android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your best bet is to look at frameworks that do this such as [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) or [Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/platform/titanium-sdk/).

another option that i have recently discovered is that if you write a [Firefox](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/mobile/developers/) mobile application then you are able to install it onto your android phone through the firefox web browser.

Answer (score 2):

> is there any official way in the google docs to start a html5 android app?

The Android developer documentation has [best practices for Web apps](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/index.html), much of which would be of relevance to HTML5 Web sites.

Answer (score 1):

you could start using one oft the Frameworks which are out there like: cocoonsJS, appMobi or phonegap

Comment: thank you, this is a good start i think